# Elasticsearch find subdomains

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I try find subdomains by main domain in elasticsearch.
I added few domains to elastic:

```
 $domains = [
    'site.com',
    'ns1.site.com',
    'ns2.site.com',
    'test.main.site.com',
    'sitesite.com',
    'test-site.com',
];
foreach ($domains as $domain) {
    $params = [
        'index' => 'my_index',
        'type' => 'my_type',
        'body' => ['domain' => $domain],
    ];
    $client->index($params);
}
```

Then I try to search:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'my_index',
    'type' => 'my_type',
    'body' => [
        'query' => [
            'wildcard' => [
                'domain' => [
                    'value' => '.site.com',
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
$response = $client->search($params);
```

But found nothing. :(

My mapping is:
https://pastebin.com/raw/k9MzjJUM

Any ideas to fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, just a couple of things missing.

### How to make an "ends with" query?

It's enough to add `*` in your query (that's why this query is called [`wildcard`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html)):

```
POST my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard" : { "domain" : "*.site.com" }
    }
}
```

This will give you the following result:

```
{
  ...
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "RoE8VGMBRuo1XmkIXhp0",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "domain": "test.main.site.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Seems to work, but we only get one of the results (not all of them).

### Why it returns not all matching documents?

Returning to your mapping, the field `domain` has type [`text`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/text.html):

```
PUT my_index
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "domain": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This means that content of that field will be tokenized and lowercased (with [standard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/analysis-standard-analyzer.html) analyzer). You can see which tokens will be actually searchable using [`_analyze` API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/indices-analyze.html), like this:

```
POST _analyze
{
  "text": "test.main.site.com"
}

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "test.main.site.com",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 18,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

That's why `wildcard` query could match `test.main.site.com`.

What if we take `n1.site.com`?

```
POST _analyze
{
  "text": "n1.site.com"
}

{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "n1",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 2,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "site.com",
      "start_offset": 3,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, there is no token that ends with `.site.com` (note the `.` before the `site.com`).

Fortunately, your mapping is already capable to return all results.

### How to return all the results for "ends with" query?

You could use [`keyword`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/keyword.html) field, which uses the exact value for querying:

```
POST my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "wildcard" : { "domain.keyword" : "*.site.com" }
    }
}
```

This will give you the following result:

```
{
  "hits": {
    "total": 3,
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "RoE8VGMBRuo1XmkIXhp0",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "domain": "test.main.site.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "Q4E8VGMBRuo1XmkIFRpy",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "domain": "ns1.site.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "my_type",
        "_id": "RYE8VGMBRuo1XmkIORqG",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "domain": "ns2.site.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

### Is this the best way to do "ends with"-like queries?

Actually, no. `wildcard` queries [can be very slow](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html):

> Note that this query can be slow, as it needs to iterate over many
>   terms. In order to prevent extremely slow wildcard queries, a wildcard
>   term should not start with one of the wildcards * or ?.

To achieve best performance, in your case, I would suggest creating another field, `higherLevelDomains`, and manually extracting the higher level domains from the original. The document might look like:

```
POST my_index/my_type
{
  "domain": "test.main.site.com",
  "higherLevelDomains": [
    "main.site.com",
    "site.com",
    "com"
  ]
}
```

This will allow you to use [`term`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/query-dsl-term-query.html) query:

```
POST my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "term" : { "higherLevelDomains.keyword" : "site.com" }
    }
}
```

This is probably the most efficient query you can get with Elasticsearch for such task.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Do you have any elasticsearch processor for extracting the higher level domains from the original?