# Elasticsearch: How to achieve a case sensitive term query?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I try to query for items by a field called unit which is case sensitive (like kWh), but my term query matches only when I query for kwh (lower case W). What I have seen in the docs is that term should be the right one for case sensitivity, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
## Create an item
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/my_id" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"point_name" : "my_point_name", "unit" : "kWh"}'
=> {"_index":"my_index","_type":"my_type","_id":"my_id","_version":1,"result":"created","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0},"created":true}

## Try to query it by unit with exact match (kWh)
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"query" : { "bool" : {"must" : [{ "term" : {"unit" : "kWh"}}]}}}'
=> {"took":36,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}

## Query with lower case unit kwh
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'{"query" : { "bool" : {"must" : [{ "term" : {"unit" : "kwh"}}]}}}'
=> {"took":12,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":1,"max_score":0.2876821,"hits":[{"_index":"my_index","_type":"my_type","_id":"my_id","_score":0.2876821,"_source":{"point_name" : "my_point_name", "unit" : "kWh"}}]}}
```

I don't want to use match here since I create these queries by other fields as well and I want to ensure an exact match behaviour. Can anyone point me how the query would be correct and why this term query does not work?

I am using this dockerimage as my server:

`docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.2.4`

Comment: You should check the type of the field `unit`. Chances are it is `text`, which is `analyzed` and will store lowercased terms. What you need instead is `keyword` type. If you are using "default" mapping then there is most likely a `unit.keyword` field which will work case-sensitive with your `term` query. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50249450/elasticsearch-find-subdomains/50306329#50306329).

Comment: Ah, thank you. The .keyword solves my problem. If you like write an answer and I will accept it

Comment: Great! That's ok, I think this question has been asked here for many times already :)